# Can colour be synthesized from frequency?

Tags: electromagnetism, visible-light, vibrations

Given the frequency of a mechanical vibration in the audible range, one can synthesize the sound on a computer. For example, I ask "what does 440Hz sound like?" and I can listen to this frequency as synthesized by the computer. However, given the frequency of an electromagnetic vibration in the visible range, can one likewise synthesize the colour of this frequency?

As I understand it, visible colours displayed on a computer are usually built up from the mixing of three primary colours. On the other hand, synthesizing colours of a specific frequency seems like a challenging problem while the sonic analog of this question is simple.

Insight(s)?

Comment: I guess I'm really interested in how you could achieve colour synthesis from frequency on a computer rather than by an RGB shceme.

Answer (score 0):

Every color you see is an electromagnetic wave, and the color depends on the frequency of the wave.

When you synthesize a sound wave, what you're actually doing is create waves of air pressure, with the frequency corresponding to a certain pitch.

If you want to "synthesize a color", what you actually want to do is to generate light, i.e, an electromagnetic field at the right frequency.

About colors being built from RGB (red, green and blue), that's not entirely true. Every EM wave in the visible spectrum, with a certain frequency, is a certain, different color. Your **eyes** can only detect RGB (because of three different types of photo-receptors clusters in your eyes), and every color "in between" is an effect created by your brain when your pick certain combinations of RGB.